# How to add reference to whole counter?

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, enumerate

I would like to create a whole reference to my enumerate list. I use package **listliketab**, so I am able to itemize inside table.

```
\begin{document}

\storestyleof {enumerate}
\begin{listliketab}
\newcounter{tabenum}\setcounter{tabenum}{0}
\newcounter{tabenumm}[tabenum] % Dodanie [tabenum] wymusza wyzerowanie tabenumm, gdy tabenum wzrosnie
\setcounter{tabenumm}{0}
\newcommand{\nextnum}{\refstepcounter{tabenum}{B\thetabenum.}}
\newcommand{\nextnumm}{\refstepcounter{tabenumm}{B\thetabenum.\thetabenumm}}


% https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=10815
\begin{tabular}{l  l | l | l}
\nextnum\label{num:Red} & Red & green & blue \\
\nextnum & Happy & sad & confused \\
\nextnumm & Happy & sad & confused \\
\nextnum & Happy & sad & confused \\
\nextnumm & Happy & sad & confused \\
\nextnumm\label{num:Reddd} & Hapyy & sad & Happy \\
\nextnum & Sad & Happy & Sad \\
\nextnumm\label{num:Redd} & Hapyy & sad & Happy \\
\end{tabular}
\end{listliketab}

Reference \ref{num:Red}
Reference \ref{num:Reddd}

\vspace{1cm}
```

When I use `\ref{num:Red} \ref{num:Reddd}` I get

```
Reference 1 Reference 2
```

But I want to receive

```
Reference B1. Reference B3.2
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Hello, welcome among us. Can you please complete the MWE so many of us can help you?  thanks. https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of references is controlled by the `\the...` commands, so if you want to be able to reference the list items with the same format as that used in the list, what you should do is to use directly `\thetabenum` and `\thetabenumm` inside of `\nextnum` and `\nextnumm`'s definitions, and modify `\thetabenum` and `\thetabenumm` to include the format.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listliketab}
\begin{document}

\storestyleof {enumerate}
\begin{listliketab}
\newcounter{tabenum}\setcounter{tabenum}{0}
\newcounter{tabenumm}[tabenum] % Dodanie [tabenum] wymusza wyzerowanie tabenumm, gdy tabenum wzrosnie
\setcounter{tabenumm}{0}
\newcommand{\nextnum}{\refstepcounter{tabenum}\thetabenum}
\newcommand{\nextnumm}{\refstepcounter{tabenumm}\thetabenumm}
\renewcommand{\thetabenum}{B\arabic{tabenum}.}
\renewcommand{\thetabenumm}{\thetabenum\arabic{tabenumm}}


% https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=10815
\begin{tabular}{l  l | l | l}
\nextnum\label{num:Red} & Red & green & blue \\
\nextnum & Happy & sad & confused \\
\nextnumm & Happy & sad & confused \\
\nextnum & Happy & sad & confused \\
\nextnumm & Happy & sad & confused \\
\nextnumm\label{num:Reddd} & Hapyy & sad & Happy \\
\nextnum & Sad & Happy & Sad \\
\nextnumm\label{num:Redd} & Hapyy & sad & Happy \\
\end{tabular}
\end{listliketab}

Reference \ref{num:Red}
Reference \ref{num:Reddd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!